# How to get rid of the none output?

Tags: python

How do I remove the NONE output when I run my code?

```
print("choose from the following options: ")

print("0 quit.")
print("1 Test is_year_same.")
print("2 Test is_leap_year.")
print("3 Test is month_name.")
print("")

choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))


def check():
  a = int(input("Enter the first year: "))
  b = int(input("Enter the first year again: "))

  if a == b:
    print("Good")
  else:
    print("Bad")


def is_leap_year():
  year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
  
  if (year % 4) == 0:
    if (year % 100) == 0:
        if (year % 400) == 0:
            print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
        else:
            print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
    else:
        print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
  else:
    print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))


def options():
  if choice == 0:
   print("0")
  if choice == 1:
    print("1")
    print(check())
  if choice == 2:
    print("2")
    print(is_leap_year())

options()
```

Sample Output:
choose from the folowing options:
0 quit.
1 Test is_year_same.
2 Test is_leap_year.
3 Test is month_name.

```
Enter your choice: 1
1
Enter the first year: 2001
Enter the first year again: 2001
Good
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
if choice == 1:
    print("1")
    print(check())
```

You are printing the value returned from `check` function. That is giving the `None` value. If you want to get rid of the `None`, remove the `print` and simply call the function as `check()`